# avr-gdb: No symbol "x" in current context

Tags: gdb, avr-gcc

I'm debugging this function compiled with `-g -ggdb -gstabs -Og` on an AVR 8-bit controller:

```
usbMsgLen_t usbFunctionSetup(uchar data[8]) {
    usbRequest_t *req = (void *)data;

    if (req->bRequest == CUSTOM_REQ_TMP) {
        // temperature in °C multiplied by 10
        int16_t tmpx10 = (mVAvgTmp >> EWMA_BS) - 500;
        // relative humidity in % multiplied by 10
        uint32_t rhx10 = (mvAvgRh * 100 - (75750 << EWMA_BS)) / (318 << EWMA_BS);
        
        static char msg[16];
        snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), "%d|%ld", tmpx10, rhx10);
        usbMsgPtr = (usbMsgPtr_t)msg;
        asm("break");
        return sizeof(msg);
    }

    // return no data for unimplemented requests
    return 0;
}
```

When execution stops at the manually inserted break instruction, `avr-gdb` prints the value of `msg` with the correct values of `tmpx10` and `rhx10`:

```
(gdb) p msg
$1 = "200|528\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"
```

but for `tmpx10` it prints a wrong value and for `rhx10`, it says `No symbol "rhx10" in current context.`:

```
(gdb) p tmpx10
$2 = 116
(gdb) p rhx10
No symbol "rhx10" in current context.
```

even though both variables are in the same scope as `msg`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`-Og` will perform minimal optimisation, but it's not *no* optimisation.  At the point you are stopped both tmpx10 and rhx10 are no longer needed, so it is possible that their locations have been reused for something else (tmpx10) or maybe that the debug info doesn't even describe the location any more (rhx10).

You're right, that -Og *should* ensure this doesn't happen, and you might consider raising a compiler bug, but the reality is that, especially when there's optimisation in use, getting these cases right all the time is hard.

I'm also curious why you're using `-gstabs`.  If you're compiler is GCC, and you're debugging with GDB, I'd have though using the default DWARF would give you better results.

Finally, when I compile for debugging, I use `-g3 -O0` which include the maximum debug information and the least (no) optimisation.  This might give you better results.

Comment: What you write about optimization sounds plausible to me. I'll try with -O0, but the program gets too large for an ATtiny45, so I'll try later with an ATtiny85. Also, I get `#warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed" [-Wcpp]` with -O0.

Comment: With `-gdwarf`, I get `$3 = <optimized out>` instead of `No symbol "rhx10" in current context.`, which is already nice. For `p tmpx10`, I still get some wrong value. But let's see with -O0.